# My Linux Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't detect my secondary monitor (noob needs help)

Tags: dvi

I have tried my best to get a second monitor working for my computer and it never seems to detect my secondary monitor. I have a DVI port on my computer on the side facing vertically. I've tried budging the plug in as tight as I can. But nothing seems to work. So I need some help. If I have to explain more to you please say so because I have no real idea to what I am doing.